# getView() not called in ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, xml, android-cardview

Currently I am using a library to display a card-like-tinder-swipe functionality ([here](https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack)) but I'm a having a little problem with the **card not displaying**. I've make sure to check my `getCount` and initialization but still it's not displaying. I'm not sure where I did wrong and I think I need a new set pair of eyes to look at this. Been at this for days. Thank you.

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.jobforhire.mobile.CardSliderActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="JobForHire"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/activity_job_list_container"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_job_list_container.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.jobforhire.mobile.CardSliderActivity"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <link.fls.swipestack.SwipeStack
    android:id="@+id/swipeStack"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:padding="32dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_job_list_card_view.xml**

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="25dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:text="Hello"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**CardSliderActivity.java**

```
 private int cardCount = 2;
private SwipeDeck cardStack;
private String token;
private ArrayList<String> testData;
private ArrayList<DataJobCards> testJsonData = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<DataPreference> dataPreferenceArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<DataPreference> dataPreferenceArrayListContainer = new ArrayList<>();
private SwipeDeckAdapter adapter;

/**
 *  Inflate a card deck and insert card into the deck
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new RetrieveCards(this,1).execute();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    token = intent.getStringExtra("access_token");

    new PrefUserAsync(this,this,token).execute();

    Fabric.with(this, new Answers());

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //toolbar.setTitle(R.string.card_title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    //getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    cardStack = (SwipeDeck) findViewById(R.id.swipe_deck);
}

@Override
public void PassCards(ArrayList<DataJobCards> arrayList) {

    this.testJsonData = arrayList;
    adapter = new SwipeDeckAdapter(testData,testJsonData,cardStack,this);
    if(cardStack != null) {
        cardStack.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("Check adapter ", "is !null");
    }
    else{
        Log.d("Check adapter ", "is null");
    }
}
```

**CardDeckAdapter.java**

```
public class CardDeckAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataJobCards> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Integer> randomImage = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<DataJobCards> cardList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CardDeckAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataJobCards> apps) {
    super(context,0,apps);
    this.cardList = apps;
    this.context = context;

     inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    Log.d("Adapter ", "Executed");
    for(int i = 0; i < cardList.size(); i++){
        Log.d("Check ", cardList.get(i).getJobTitle());
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    Log.d("getView ", "Executed");

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_job_list_card_view, parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    DataJobCards dataJobCard = getItem(position);

    holder.name.setText(dataJobCard.getJobTitle());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cardList.size();
}

@Override
public DataJobCards getItem(int position) {
    return cardList.get(position);

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
}
}
```

**EDIT**
Still no progress with this so I placed a little bit more code from my main class which is `CardSliderActivity.java`just in case there's something in my main class has anything to do with it.

Comment: Are you sure the library you're using is the one you linked?
It has nothing related and it seems to be that one instead: https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack
Can you please update your question and make you provide accurate data for us to help you?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I was so tired last night when I posted this and might've gotten confused. I've updated it.

Comment: Trim down your code to the bare minimum. If you still haven't solved the problem by then, post the smaller code. This is too much code.

Comment: I did post it on a bare minimum earlier but it seems that the problem might have something to do with my all or all of the code that I posted. And also I don't think I deserved that -1. I asked my question after doing some researches, what normally could cause it, and I think I'm being specific :)

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess since I cannot see SwipeStack view defined in your xml. Your swipeStack object might be null so the adapter is not set. Can you verify?

Comment: Sorry it was a copy paste error. SwipeStack is under the container. I've updated it.

Comment: I tried running your app and it seems to work on me. I can only speculate again, since I cannot see your entire Activity code. Can you make sure that arrayList is not cleared in your activity at some point? Since your activity and your adapter shares the same instance of the list, clearing it in Activity will also clear it in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote **activity_job_list_view.xml** as filename when showing us the code. But later, in the getView method you inflate **R.layout.activity_job_list_card_view**. Is it possibile you got confused with the names? Or is it just a typo you made here on stackoverflow?

Comment: Sorry. It's a typo. It's really late here and I'm very tired. I've updated it.

Comment: Ok, well... for now I can't find any more errors. I'm sorry.

Comment: It's okay. Thank you for your efforts :)